# Pushing data to the Cloud through Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Is it possible to push local data to the cloud through forge, in the form of an application, possibly a c# application?

I just want to know if it is possible for me to push constant static data to the cloud using Autodesk Forge? such as a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you can - simply follow the tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket/).

And be sure to create a persistent bucket if you would like to keep your uploads. See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/) for details.